# WP Как создать начальный .PO файл локализации

Tags: wordpress, геолокация, locale

Подскажите, как создать изначальный файл для локализации? В большинстве видео уроков по Wordpress все используют poeditor в качестве старта, но если создаться начальная тема без папки language/ и начального перевода.
Не получается разобраться как сделать что б все вставки по типу `<?php _e( 'Test text', 'new-template'); ?>` можно было получить в этот .po файл

Comment: В poedit есть средство сканирования файлов плагина, все gettext аргументы попадут в po файл

Comment: Ещё можно использовать этот плагин если нет poedit
https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/